# Jenkins: build status and definition of stable

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying out my first Jenkins job. I have been able to configure to a point where Jenkins build checks Git and runs my simple script.

However, beyond this, I don't know how Jenkins gets the status of the test I am running using script? I see that Jenkins has a notion of "stable build". So, probably it does get status from scripts back but I don't know how.

Can someone throw light on this please?

Comment: how do you run the script? using shell step? usually it depends on the script exit code

Answer (score 0):

All the usual steps (maven, ant, shell, etc.) launch a command. The [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of that command determines whether the build step was successful (exit code = 0) or not (exit code <> 0).

You can try it by running shell with these very simple scripts (first one is successful):

```
exit 0
```

(the second one failed)

```
exit 1
```

By default, failure of any build step causes skipping all the further steps and only post-build actions are performed. Among post-build actions there are few that can change the whole build status (e.g. Jenkins text finder) - to stable, unstable or failed.

Comment: thanks. I did realize later that I have to return exit codes. I have done that and all looks good. As a side point, I could not find this basic fact in Jenkins documentation. If I have missed, please point me to it?

Comment: I can't find it either in the doc, to be honest. Only some mentions in the Pipeline chapter. It seems the Jenkins developers feel this feature as obvious.

Comment: Someone has requested a definition in the docs:  
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10763